# ReactDOM.render not rendering the component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using nodeJS with react.

to install react in my node I used.

```
npm install --save react react-dom
```

This is my index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="Script/script.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ExperimentForm"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.jsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

```
var FormComponent = React.createClass({
  render :function(){
  return(<h2>Hello World</h2>);
  }

})

ReactDOM.render(<FormComponent />, document.getElementById("ExperimentForm"));
```

I have tried using

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

but that also doesn't worked.

my app.js is

```
var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

    var config = {
      appRoot: __dirname // required config
    };

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

    app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
      console.log("index page");
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
    });

    console.log(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
    SwaggerExpress.create(config, function (err, swaggerExpress) {
      console.log("Starting server");
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }


      swaggerExpress.register(app);


      const port = 11011;
      const server = app.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Server started @ %s!', port);
      });


    });
```

in google developer tool I don't see any error , it seems to load the index.html but is not displaying anything in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `import` to get `react` and `react-dom`. You have to explicitly import them using the `script` tags from their cdn. Also to enable parsing of `jsx`, you need `babel-core` too. Just remove `import` statements from `script.jsx` and your `index.html` should look like this

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="ExperimentForm"></div>
    <script src="Script/script.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , so what is the use case of npm install --save react react-dom, so if we include cdnjs in script we don't need to install these react packages ?

Comment: @bhavesh The above method is one way of creating react applications. But usually this method is not preferred. Other way is to create the react app independently. In that way you install react, dom etc using `npm install` and then bundle them up using tools like `webpack`.

Comment: @bhavesh I would recommend to use https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app . You can directly start using react without worrying about various configurations.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is:

```
npm install webpack babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

In your package.json inside script tag add this:

```
"scripts": {
"pack": "webpack"
// other default script tag here
}
```

create a **deploy** folder in your app root directory

create **webpack.config.js** in your app root directory and paste the following json

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry:"./<replace with your js file entry point>",
  output:{
  path: __dirname+"/deploy",
  filename:"app.js"
},
module:{
  loaders:[
  { test:/\.js$/, exclude:/node_modules/, loader:"babel-loader" }
]
}};
```

what it does is bundle your all js file into a single js file and save it inside the deploy folder filename app.js

Next create a **.babelrc** in app root directory and include the following json

```
 {
   "presets":[
   "es2015",
   "react"
   ]
 }
```

This makes sure babel understand es6 and react syntax.

Comment: In this method do I need to include cdn script in by index.js file ? importing react and ReactDom should work ?

Comment: you will not require CDN anymore if you install using npm install --save react react-dom. You create and index.js file where you import react and react-dom and include that as entry point in the webpack.config.js. There you write your react code 
var FormComponent = React.createClass({
  render :function(){
  return(<h2>Hello World</h2>);
  }

})

ReactDOM.render(<FormComponent />, document.getElementById("ExperimentForm"));